# Redirect to https with www for particulate domain on HAproxy

Tags: server, apache2, haproxy, varnish

I've setup Haproxy, varnish and apache2 on ubuntu server and there are multiple web site running with http and https.

following setup configured as below:

```
---443--> |
          | HAProxy ------>Varnish(8081) ----------> apache2(8080)
---80---> |
```

haproxy.cfg

```
frontend http-example
bind *:80


frontend https-example
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.in/example.pem
    mode http
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https

    default_backend example

backend example
    stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
    acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
    acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if clienthello
    tcp-response content accept if serverhello
    stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello
    stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello

    server varnish 127.0.0.1:8081 check
```

Plan:

HAproxy : 
Here I have to configure, if user execute `exmaple.com` and `www.example.in` then redirect to `https://example.in` -For https

if `example1.in` then redirect to `www.exmaple1.in`and so on.